# Google Chart into Infowindow

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, charts, google-visualization

I can't seem to find a good solution on the internet that suited the current problem. I want to show the google chart into the infowindow. But I kept on getting an empty one. Can anyone please help me out?

Here is a copy of the markers code and with  the infowindow. It is inside a loop so that I could get multiple markers.

```
    for (i = 0; i < get_markers.length; i++) { 

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(get_markers[i][1], get_markers[i][2]),
                map: map});

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',(function(marker, i,infowindow) 
        {
            return function() {

                        var con = '<div id="chart_div1"></div>';

            infowindow.setContent(con);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

            drawChart(this);
        }

    })(marker, i,infowindow));
     markers.push(marker);
```

This is how I was able to view my google chart.(Not inside the infowindow)

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
  var options = {
      title: 'By Crime Type',
      is3D: 'true',
      width: 500,
      height: 300
    };
 var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
  chart.draw(data, options);}
```

I want to put the google chart inside the infowindow. Any suggestions is definitely appreciated. Thank you! Please do help me solve this problem.

I know there are lots of incidents like this but I wasn't able to follow them because I am still a newbie in this google chart field.

Answer (score 0):

for (i = 0; i < get_markers.length; i++) {

```
        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(get_markers[i][1], get_markers[i][2]),
                map: map});

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
        drawChart(this);
        window.location.href="?brgy_id="+get_markers[i][0];
        infowindow.open(map,marker);

        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
{
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map,
        icon: locations[i][2]
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    addInfoWindow(marker, locations[i][3]);
}

function addInfoWindow(marker, message) 
{
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: message
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        //infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        drawChart(map, marker);
    });
}

function drawChart(map, marker) {
    //Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
    ['Customer Coverage', 14],
    ['Call Average', 09],
    ['MTP Deviation', 04],
    ['SGPI Compliance', 06],
    ['Campaign Compliance', 05]
    ]);

    //Set chart options
    var options = {
        'title': 'KPI',
        'width': 300,
        'height': 150
    };

    var node = document.createElement('div'),
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(node);

    chart.draw(data, options);
    infoWindow.setContent(node);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
```

[image: info]